# Using hive variable in regex

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'd like to extract texts based on some key words from Hive database.

It works if my script looks like,

```
SELECT text
FROM table
WHERE text RLIKE '.?(aaa|bbb|ccc).?';
```

But in order to make the script more readable, I'd like to set the key words as a variable in hive. But the script fails if it looks like,

```
SET hivevar:KeyWords='.?(aaa|bbb|ccc).?';

SELECT text
FROM table
WHERE text RLIKE ${hivevar:KeyWords};
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Fu

Comment: Just FYI: The `'.?(aaa|bbb|ccc).?'` is actually the same as `'aaa|bbb|ccc'` in this case, you are using it with `RLIKE`.

Comment: Try `set KeyWords='aaa|bbb|ccc'` and then `RLIKE ${hiveconf:KeyWords}`. What is your Hive version? The `hivevar` variables can be used with the 0.8.0 version and higher.

Comment: "script fails"? - There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Still get error information like 'FAILED: ParseException line 16:31 cannot recognize input near 'RLIKE' '$' '(' in expression specification'

Comment: I have 2 ideas. **(1)** Please share the real table name (obviously not `table`) and column name (probably not `text`) **(2)** check the value of `set hive.variable.substitute`

Comment: I believed error occurred because RLIKE treated ${hivevar:KeyWords} as a regular expression instead of a variable name, and failed to explain it. But I have no idea about how to fix it. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: violetefu, what about my last comment?

Answer (score 1):

I use hivevar for variable substitution:

```
set myVar='.?(aaa|bbb|ccc).?';
select * from <your table> where <your column> RLIKE ${myVar};
```

edit:fixing brain fart...